# AS3 Spectrum visualization based on local sound driver played sound?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, itunes, audio, spectrum

**Question?**

I was wondering if it is possible to access information on the sound currently being played locally(Sound not originating from the AIR app) with AS3?

**My goal:**

Say I'm running iTunes, or spotify with my favorite song, And then i open up my Air app, The Air app picks up the information on the sound being played and shows me spectrum visualization on that song.

**Potential Problems**

I realize that this is likely not possible, due to app restrictions, and potential abuse.

Im looking forward to your response, and clarification on the subject

best regards
M

Comment: You could look at some of Grant Skinner's work:  http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2009/07/source_code_spe.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is just the spectrum visualization. The real problem is to get the data from the local sound channel

Comment: You'll need to load the sound file into the Air App...

Comment: I dont know if my explanation of my problem isent good enough but, making sound spectrum visualization by loading in a sound is **not** what I'm asking. Im trying to do visualization based on sound not originating from the AIR app.

Comment: If the AIR app dose not know what sound you are playing, what will it visualize? If you are playing the sound from another application, how it know what are you playing?You could potentially take info from sound driver(although not sure if you can and how), but than again, what if two songs are playing on same time? You must let know the application what are you visualizing, and you can do that with URLLoader class if you don't want embedding the file...

Comment: That is exactly what I'm trying to find out. How to get information from the sound driver. But as you, i don't know if this is possible?